# Break out an alphabetized list by starting letter [C#]

Tags: c#, string, list, alphabetical

I have a list, it's already sorted in alphabetical order. I'd like to break it into sections corresponding with the letter is starts with, like so:

**A**

- aListItem1
- aListItem2
- aListItem3

**B**

- bListItem1
- bListItem2
- bListItem3

**C**

- cListItem1
- cListItem2
- cListItem3

...

I could do something like:

foreach item in list
  if item startsWith A
  ... do something
  if item startsWith B
  ... do something
  if item startsWith C
  ... do something

etc...

but is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: i guess you doin' in right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep track of the current first letter as you go:

```
char first = '\0';
foreach(string item in list){
     if(item[0] != first){
         first = item[0];
         Console.WriteLine(first);
     }

     Console.WriteLine("  *  " + item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution was the best one since I could adapt it to support the IEnumerable<dynamic> collection I was iterating through. The LINQ methods weren't working with the dynamic objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Linq GroupBy method to create your sections:

```
foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(i => i[0]))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Section: " + group.Key);

   foreach (var elt in group)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(elt);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<string>() {"a1", "a2", "b1", "b2"};
var grouped = from item in list
              group item by item.First() into g
              select new {StartsWith = g.Key, Items = g};
```